# Dell XPS 13 9360 (i7 8550u) cannot recognize my logitech m590 bluetooth mouse

Tags: wireless, mouse, bluetooth, xps, logitech

Hi I'm quite new to Linux. Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and my laptop cannot seem to recognize my bluetooth mouse (logitech m590). Fresh install, updated via terminal. The computer *can* detect my bluetooth speaker, however, so I guess the hardware is working. But when I switched back to WIN10 my mouse will work fine. Could someone please let me know if you are encountering the same problem or if there is a solution? Thank you!

Comment: No amswer or help I'm afraid but I have an XPS 13 and logitech mx anywhere bluetooth mouse and it "just worked" - the laptop battery level indicator in kubuntu even shows the mouse charge when I click on it. I had to fiddle about a bit with a hidden button on the mouse to get it paired (I lost the instructioms) but once done it has worked flawlessly ever since. I would guess even if it is paired under Windows you will have to do it again under ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I have come to the conclusion that Logitech m590 does not work with Linux natively. On their product spec page it says that only the receiver works with Linux kernel 2.6. Here's the link to the page:

https://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/Compatible-operating-systems-for-the-M585-Multi-Device-and-M590-Multi-Device-Silent

Comment: I have the M585 and it doesn't work on Ubuntu 19.10 either. I guess same issue, however your like is broken. Thanks.